# How to schedule job using time zone from specific location, not UTC

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm using the Quartz.net scheduler for the first time. I'm trying to run a specific process for different locations based on the locations time zone. I wanted to pass the schedule dynamically say the time and the location details to the scheduler. How can I achieve that. Any help here is much appreciated. Below is the code that I'm at right now. My Problem right now is that if do a for loop of all the below code I can process only one record at a time which is going to hit the performance or if I just include the datamap logic in the for loop only the last record will be send when the scheduler is actually started and I don't know how to pass the time to the trigger as it is out of the loop.

```
public ISchedulerFactory objSchedulerFact;
        private IScheduler objScheduler;

protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {


            objScheduler =  objSchedulerFact.GetScheduler();

          IJobDetail objEslJobDet = JobBuilder.Create<ESLPriceAuditProcessor>()
                .WithIdentity("ESLJob", "ESL")
                .Build();

            objEslJobDet.JobDataMap.Put("Location", 100); // Pass the value here dynamically by taking the data from a table

            IJobDetail objSignJobDet = JobBuilder.Create<SignPriceAuditProcessor>()
                .WithIdentity("SignJob", "Sign")
                .Build();
            objSignJobDet.JobDataMap.Put("Location", 200);

            ITrigger objESLJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("ESLTrigger", "ESL")
                .StartAt(DateTime.Today.AddHours(2)) //Pass the time hours dynamically. I wanted execute the process for the given location based on the location time, say 4 AM at their respective timezone. Example, if i'm running the code on the server in CST time zone and I want to run this process for a EST location at current time CST Time + 2 hours and so on. I can configure the number of hours difference in the database based on the location, but how can I pass that dynamically.   
                .EndAt(DateTime.Today.AddHours(22))
                .WithSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.Create().WithIntervalInHours(4))
                .Build();

            ITrigger objSignJobTrigger = TriggerBuilder.Create()
                .WithIdentity("SignTrigger", "SIGN")
                .StartAt(DateTime.Today.AddHours(4)) 
                .EndAt(DateTime.Today.AddHours(22))
                .WithSchedule(SimpleScheduleBuilder.Create().WithIntervalInHours(4))
                .Build();


            objScheduler.ScheduleJob(objEslJobDet, objESLJobTrigger);
            objScheduler.ScheduleJob(objSignJobDet, objSignJobTrigger);
            objScheduler.Start();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17080257/2833802) SO answer. The main points are that

> You really should never be dependent on the time zone of the server that your code is running on. Server code should be time zone neutral. The only place where you should ever involve DateTime.Now or TimeZoneInfo.Local or any similar functionality is in desktop or mobile applications. Server code should only depend on UTC.

as time zone offsets are not constant and many time zones switch offset for daylight saving time (a.k.a. "Summer Time").