# UTC Time different on servers in different timezones?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, datetime, timezone

On my dev server I save a value called "ScheduledDateUtc" date to sqlserver e.g. 24-11-14 09:00:00. I also save a value called "UtcOffset" and calculate the "ScheduledDateLocal" like so:

```
var ScheduledDateLocal = ScheduledDateUtc.AddHours(UtcOffset); //a negative offset would be deducted and a positive offset would be added
```

On my dev server this works fine and its calculates the correct ScheduledDateLocal for alle timezones/UtcOffset's. However, when I deploy to a Azure server in a different timezone this calculation is a few hours off.

Can anyone explain why? I'm guessing there is some kind of setting or system specific conversion param? Thanks!

Comment: Do you know what timezone your Azure server is located in?

Comment: Im in UTC+1 and the calculation is one hour too much so Im guessing UTC0

Comment: My guess would be that you're initialising ScheduledDateUtc as a Utc datetime However, I'd expect it to be incorrect n your machine not on Azure which I'd assume is on Utc. I think we need to see an example input, output on your machine and the output on Azure.

Comment: Stephen is likely correct, but also - if these are truly *scheduled* values in the future, then storing as UTC is incorrect to begin with.  Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19627330/634824) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19170823/634824).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the incorrect result is actually on your machine and not Azure, and is because you are initialising `ScheduledDateUtc` as local time and not UTC?

Consider these two lines of code:

```
new DateTime(2015, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1).AddHours(5).ToUniversalTime().Dump();

new DateTime(2015, 6, 1, 1, 1, 1, DateTimeKind.Utc).AddHours(5).ToUniversalTime().Dump();
```

Here, we are in summer time which is UTC+1. The output of the above is:

> 01/06/2015 05:01:01
>
> 01/06/2015 06:01:01

They're 1 hour out as I 'forgot' to specify that the input is UTC in the constructor in the first line of code.

If you don't have access to the constructor because `ScheduledDateUtc` is initialised by an ORM, you can use `SpecifyKind`:

```
ScheduledDateUtc = DateTime.SpecifyKind(ScheduledDateUtc, DateTimeKind.Utc)
```

Its unfortunate that you're storing an offset not a timezone as you may have issues with daylight savings time. If you were storing a Windows timezone name, you could use `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` (no need to specify `Kind` here as this assumes UTC) as per this example from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.converttimefromutc(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TimeZoneInfo cstZone = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Central Standard Time");
ScheduledDateLocal = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc(ScheduledDateUtc, cstZone);
```

You **could** instead instantiate a ["custom" timezone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.createcustomtimezone(v=vs.110).aspx) using your offset and still use the above function.

I faced a [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7553997/how-does-datetimeoffset-deal-with-daylight-saving-time) where I had to schedule events based on a user's local time. I ended up storing the day of the week, hour, minute, and [Olson timezone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) string, and used [Noda-Time](http://nodatime.org/) to convert to a [DateTimeOffset](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset(v=vs.110).aspx) and from there to server time.

Comment: This is interesting. Thanks. Will try it tomorow