# Converting Olson TZID to Windows Time Zone

Tags: windows, timezone

I'm looking for a table to convert all of the Olson TZIDs to Windows time zones.  I have found:

[.NET TimeZoneInfo from Olson time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996320/net-timezoneinfo-from-olson-time-zone)

Which is great and can be built from the info at:

http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml

but unfortunately it only maps some of the TZIDs to the Windows time zones. Has anyone come across (or produced) a full table?

Comment: That's forever the problem, timezones are not picked by logical lines on a map, they are picked by people that can vote and pick whatever suits them.  Especially a problem with daylight savings time.  Joining the databases that they try to keep updated just produces the smallest intersection.  Use UTC.

Comment: I'd love to use UTC, but this is a calendar application and I require the timezone.  

Specifically, my source is iCal, which often contains Olson TZIDs as part of time specifications.  I have put together a table containing those TZIDs and offsets which converts those times to UTC.  However, this data needs to get into another system where the timezone must be specified, and it must be a Windows timezone.  

I was hoping someone may have done this before to save the job of manually going through every zone.

Comment: The same problem - we are implementing PHP-compatible TZ functions using .NET TimeZoneInfo (http://phalanger.codeplex.com/), this table helped us a lot!

Comment: By design certain time zones will not map. Refer to the unmappable time zone section here: http://cldr.unicode.org/development/development-process/design-proposals/extended-windows-olson-zid-mapping. Can you provide more information on specific conversions that aren't working so we can exclude the cases that don't work by design of the CLDR mapping?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

OK, so I have had a bash at putting together a table.  I'm quite sure there are lots of inaccuracies and there are many zones that don't map, but it will do for my purposes for now.

Update, the following page also looks to have good info: http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml

```
Olson TZID,UTC Offset,Windows Timezone ID,Windows Display Name
Pacific/Apia,-11,Samoa Standard Time,(UTC-11:00) Samoa
Pacific/Midway,-11,Hawaiian Standard Time,(UTC-10:00) Hawaii
Pacific/Niue,-11,Samoa Standard Time,(UTC-11:00) Samoa
Pacific/Pago_Pago,-11,Samoa Standard Time,(UTC-11:00) Samoa
America/Adak,-10,Hawaiian Standard Time,(UTC-10:00) Hawaii
Pacific/Fakaofo,-10,Hawaiian Standard Time,(UTC-10:00) Hawaii
Pacific/Honolulu,-10,Hawaiian Standard Time,(UTC-10:00) Hawaii
Pacific/Johnston,-10,Hawaiian Standard Time,(UTC-10:00) Hawaii
Pacific/Rarotonga,-10,Hawaiian Standard Time,(UTC-10:00) Hawaii
Pacific/Tahiti,-10,Hawaiian Standard Time,(UTC-10:00) Hawaii
Pacific/Marquesas,-9.5,Hawaiian Standard Time,(UTC-10:00) Hawaii
America/Anchorage,-9,Alaskan Standard Time,(UTC-09:00) Alaska
America/Juneau,-9,Alaskan Standard Time,(UTC-09:00) Alaska
America/Nome,-9,Alaskan Standard Time,(UTC-09:00) Alaska
America/Yakutat,-9,Alaskan Standard Time,(UTC-09:00) Alaska
Pacific/Gambier,-9,Alaskan Standard Time,(UTC-09:00) Alaska
America/Dawson,-8,Pacific Standard Time,(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) 
America/Los_Angeles,-8,Pacific Standard Time,(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) 
America/Santa_Isabel,-8,Pacific Standard Time (Mexico),(UTC-08:00) Baja California
America/Tijuana,-8,Pacific Standard Time (Mexico),(UTC-08:00) Baja California
America/Vancouver,-8,Pacific Standard Time,(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) 
America/Whitehorse,-8,Pacific Standard Time,(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) 
Pacific/Pitcairn,-8,Pacific Standard Time,(UTC-08:00) Pacific Time (US & Canada) 
America/Boise,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Cambridge_Bay,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Chihuahua,-7,Mountain Standard Time (Mexico),"(UTC-07:00) Chihuahua, La Paz, Mazatlan"
America/Dawson_Creek,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Denver,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Edmonton,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Hermosillo,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Inuvik,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Mazatlan,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Ojinaga,-7,US Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Arizona
America/Phoenix,-7,US Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Arizona
America/Shiprock,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Yellowknife,-7,Mountain Standard Time,(UTC-07:00) Mountain Time (US & Canada)
America/Belize,-6,Central America Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central America
America/Cancun,-6,Central Standard Time (Mexico),"(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey"
America/Chicago,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Costa_Rica,-6,Central America Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central America
America/El_Salvador,-6,Central America Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central America
America/Guatemala,-6,Central America Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central America
America/Indiana/Knox,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Indiana/Tell_City,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Managua,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Matamoros,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Menominee,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Merida,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Mexico_City,-6,Central Standard Time (Mexico),"(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey"
America/Monterrey,-6,Central Standard Time (Mexico),"(UTC-06:00) Guadalajara, Mexico City, Monterrey"
America/North_Dakota/Center,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/North_Dakota/New_Salem,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Rainy_River,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Rankin_Inlet,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Regina,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Swift_Current,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Tegucigalpa,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
America/Winnipeg,-6,Central Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)
Pacific/Easter,-6,Central America Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central America
Pacific/Galapagos,-6,Central America Standard Time,(UTC-06:00) Central America
America/Atikokan,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Bogota,-5,SA Pacific Standard Time,"(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito"
America/Cayman,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Detroit,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Grand_Turk,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Guayaquil,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Havana,-5,SA Pacific Standard Time,"(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito"
America/Indiana/Indianapolis,-5,US Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)
America/Indiana/Marengo,-5,US Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)
America/Indiana/Petersburg,-5,US Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)
America/Indiana/Vevay,-5,US Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)
America/Indiana/Vincennes,-5,US Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)
America/Indiana/Winamac,-5,US Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Indiana (East)
America/Iqaluit,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Jamaica,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Kentucky/Louisville,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Kentucky/Monticello,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Lima,-5,SA Pacific Standard Time,"(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito"
America/Montreal,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Nassau,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/New_York,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Nipigon,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Panama,-5,SA Pacific Standard Time,"(UTC-05:00) Bogota, Lima, Quito"
America/Pangnirtung,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Port-au-Prince,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Resolute,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Thunder_Bay,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Toronto,-5,Eastern Standard Time,(UTC-05:00) Eastern Time (US & Canada)
America/Caracas,-4.5,Venezuela Standard Time,(UTC-04:30) Caracas
America/Anguilla,-4,Pacific SA Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Santiago
America/Antigua,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Aruba,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Asuncion,-4,Paraguay Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Asuncion
America/Barbados,-4,Pacific SA Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Santiago
America/Blanc-Sablon,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Boa_Vista,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Campo_Grande,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Cuiaba,-4,Central Brazilian Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Cuiaba
America/Curacao,-4,Central Brazilian Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Cuiaba
America/Dominica,-4,Pacific SA Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Santiago
America/Eirunepe,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Glace_Bay,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Goose_Bay,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Grenada,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Guadeloupe,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Guyana,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Halifax,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/La_Paz,-4,SA Western Standard Time,"(UTC-04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan"
America/Manaus,-4,SA Western Standard Time,"(UTC-04:00) Georgetown, La Paz, Manaus, San Juan"
America/Marigot,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Martinique,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Moncton,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Montserrat,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Port_of_Spain,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Porto_Velho,-4,Central Brazilian Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Cuiaba
America/Puerto_Rico,-4,Central Brazilian Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Cuiaba
America/Rio_Branco,-4,Central Brazilian Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Cuiaba
America/Santiago,-4,Pacific SA Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Santiago
America/Santo_Domingo,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/St_Barthelemy,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/St_Kitts,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/St_Lucia,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/St_Thomas,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/St_Vincent,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Thule,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/Tortola,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
Antarctica/Palmer,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
Atlantic/Bermuda,-4,Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-04:00) Atlantic Time (Canada)
America/St_Johns,-3.5,Newfoundland Standard Time,(UTC-03:30) Newfoundland
America/Araguaina,-3,E. South America Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Brasilia
America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/Catamarca,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/Cordoba,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/Jujuy,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/La_Rioja,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/Mendoza,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/Salta,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/San_Juan,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/San_Luis,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/Tucuman,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Argentina/Ushuaia,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Bahia,-3,E. South America Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Brasilia
America/Belem,-3,E. South America Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Brasilia
America/Cayenne,-3,SA Eastern Standard Time,"(UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza"
America/Fortaleza,-3,SA Eastern Standard Time,"(UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza"
America/Godthab,-3,Greenland Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Greenland 
America/Maceio,-3,E. South America Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Brasilia
America/Miquelon,-3,E. South America Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Brasilia
America/Montevideo,-3,Montevideo Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Montevideo
America/Paramaribo,-3,SA Eastern Standard Time,"(UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza"
America/Recife,-3,SA Eastern Standard Time,"(UTC-03:00) Cayenne, Fortaleza"
America/Santarem,-3,E. South America Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Brasilia
America/Sao_Paulo,-3,E. South America Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Brasilia
Antarctica/Rothera,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
Atlantic/Stanley,-3,Argentina Standard Time,(UTC-03:00) Buenos Aires
America/Noronha,-2,Mid-Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-02:00) Mid-Atlantic
Atlantic/South_Georgia,-2,Mid-Atlantic Standard Time,(UTC-02:00) Mid-Atlantic
America/Scoresbysund,-1,Azores Standard Time,(UTC-01:00) Azores
Atlantic/Azores,-1,Azores Standard Time,(UTC-01:00) Azores
Atlantic/Cape_Verde,-1,Cape Verde Standard Time,(UTC-01:00) Cape Verde Is.
Africa/Abidjan,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Accra,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Bamako,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Banjul,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Bissau,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Casablanca,0,Morocco Standard Time,(UTC) Casablanca
Africa/Conakry,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Dakar,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/El_Aaiun,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Freetown,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Lome,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Monrovia,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Nouakchott,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Ouagadougou,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Africa/Sao_Tome,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
America/Danmarkshavn,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Antarctica/Vostok,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Atlantic/Canary,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Atlantic/Faroe,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Atlantic/Madeira,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Atlantic/Reykjavik,0,Greenwich Standard Time,"(UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik"
Atlantic/St_Helena,0,Greenwich Standard Time,"(UTC) Monrovia, Reykjavik"
Europe/Dublin,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Europe/Guernsey,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Europe/Isle_of_Man,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Europe/Jersey,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Europe/Lisbon,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
Europe/London,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
GMT,0,GMT Standard Time,"(UTC) Dublin, Edinburgh, Lisbon, London"
UTC,0,UTC,(UTC) Coordinated Universal Time
Africa/Algiers,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Bangui,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Brazzaville,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Ceuta,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Douala,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Kinshasa,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Lagos,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Libreville,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Luanda,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Malabo,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Ndjamena,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Niamey,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Porto-Novo,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Tunis,1,W. Central Africa Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) West Central Africa
Africa/Windhoek,1,Namibia Standard Time,(UTC+01:00) Windhoek
Arctic/Longyearbyen,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Amsterdam,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Andorra,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Belgrade,1,Central Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague"
Europe/Berlin,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Bratislava,1,Central Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague"
Europe/Brussels,1,Romance Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris"
Europe/Budapest,1,Central Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague"
Europe/Copenhagen,1,Romance Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris"
Europe/Gibraltar,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Ljubljana,1,Central Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague"
Europe/Luxembourg,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Madrid,1,Romance Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris"
Europe/Malta,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Monaco,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Oslo,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Paris,1,Romance Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris"
Europe/Podgorica,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Prague,1,Central Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Belgrade, Bratislava, Budapest, Ljubljana, Prague"
Europe/Rome,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/San_Marino,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Sarajevo,1,Central Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb"
Europe/Skopje,1,Central Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb"
Europe/Stockholm,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Tirane,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Vaduz,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Vatican,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Vienna,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Europe/Warsaw,1,Central Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb"
Europe/Zagreb,1,Central Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Sarajevo, Skopje, Warsaw, Zagreb"
Europe/Zurich,1,W. Europe Standard Time,"(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna"
Africa/Blantyre,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Bujumbura,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Cairo,2,Egypt Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Cairo
Africa/Gaborone,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Harare,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Johannesburg,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Kigali,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Lubumbashi,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Lusaka,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Maputo,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Maseru,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Mbabane,2,South Africa Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Harare, Pretoria"
Africa/Tripoli,2,Middle East Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Beirut
Asia/Amman,2,Jordan Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Amman
Asia/Beirut,2,Middle East Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Beirut
Asia/Damascus,2,Syria Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Damascus
Asia/Gaza,2,Middle East Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Beirut
Asia/Jerusalem,2,Israel Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Jerusalem 
Asia/Nicosia,2,GTB Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest"
Europe/Athens,2,GTB Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest"
Europe/Bucharest,2,GTB Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest"
Europe/Chisinau,2,E. Europe Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Minsk
Europe/Helsinki,2,FLE Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius"
Europe/Istanbul,2,Turkey Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Istanbul 
Europe/Kiev,2,E. Europe Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Minsk
Europe/Mariehamn,2,E. Europe Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Minsk
Europe/Riga,2,FLE Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius"
Europe/Simferopol,2,E. Europe Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Minsk
Europe/Sofia,2,FLE Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius"
Europe/Tallinn,2,FLE Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius"
Europe/Uzhgorod,2,E. Europe Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Minsk
Europe/Vilnius,2,FLE Standard Time,"(UTC+02:00) Helsinki, Kyiv, Riga, Sofia, Tallinn, Vilnius"
Europe/Zaporozhye,2,E. Europe Standard Time,(UTC+02:00) Minsk
Africa/Addis_Ababa,3,E. Africa Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Nairobi
Africa/Asmara,3,E. Africa Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Nairobi
Africa/Dar_es_Salaam,3,E. Africa Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Nairobi
Africa/Djibouti,3,E. Africa Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Nairobi
Africa/Juba,3,E. Africa Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Nairobi
Africa/Kampala,3,E. Africa Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Nairobi
Africa/Khartoum,3,E. Africa Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Nairobi
Africa/Mogadishu,3,E. Africa Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Nairobi
Africa/Nairobi,3,E. Africa Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Nairobi
Antarctica/Syowa,3,Kaliningrad Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Kaliningrad
Asia/Aden,3,Kaliningrad Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Kaliningrad
Asia/Baghdad,3,Arabic Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Baghdad
Asia/Bahrain,3,Arabic Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Baghdad
Asia/Kuwait,3,Arab Standard Time,"(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh"
Asia/Qatar,3,Arab Standard Time,"(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh"
Asia/Riyadh,3,Arab Standard Time,"(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh"
Europe/Kaliningrad,3,Kaliningrad Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Kaliningrad
Europe/Minsk,3,Kaliningrad Standard Time,(UTC+03:00) Kaliningrad
Indian/Antananarivo,3,Arab Standard Time,"(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh"
Indian/Comoro,3,Arab Standard Time,"(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh"
Indian/Mayotte,3,Arab Standard Time,"(UTC+03:00) Kuwait, Riyadh"
Asia/Tehran,3.5,Iran Standard Time,(UTC+03:30) Tehran 
Asia/Baku,4,Caucasus Standard Time,(UTC+04:00) Yerevan
Asia/Dubai,4,Arabian Standard Time,"(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat"
Asia/Muscat,4,Arabian Standard Time,"(UTC+04:00) Abu Dhabi, Muscat"
Asia/Tbilisi,4,Georgian Standard Time,(UTC+04:00) Tbilisi 
Asia/Yerevan,4,Caucasus Standard Time,(UTC+04:00) Yerevan
Europe/Moscow,4,Russian Standard Time,"(UTC+04:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd"
Europe/Samara,4,Russian Standard Time,"(UTC+04:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd"
Europe/Volgograd,4,Russian Standard Time,"(UTC+04:00) Moscow, St. Petersburg, Volgograd"
Indian/Mahe,4,Mauritius Standard Time,(UTC+04:00) Port Louis 
Indian/Mauritius,4,Mauritius Standard Time,(UTC+04:00) Port Louis 
Indian/Reunion,4,Mauritius Standard Time,(UTC+04:00) Port Louis 
Asia/Kabul,4.5,Afghanistan Standard Time,(UTC+04:30) Kabul
Asia/Aqtau,5,West Asia Standard Time,(UTC+05:00) Tashkent 
Asia/Aqtobe,5,West Asia Standard Time,(UTC+05:00) Tashkent 
Asia/Ashgabat,5,West Asia Standard Time,(UTC+05:00) Tashkent 
Asia/Dushanbe,5,West Asia Standard Time,(UTC+05:00) Tashkent 
Asia/Karachi,5,Pakistan Standard Time,"(UTC+05:00) Islamabad, Karachi"
Asia/Oral,5,West Asia Standard Time,(UTC+05:00) Tashkent 
Asia/Samarkand,5,West Asia Standard Time,(UTC+05:00) Tashkent 
Asia/Tashkent,5,West Asia Standard Time,(UTC+05:00) Tashkent 
Indian/Kerguelen,5,West Asia Standard Time,(UTC+05:00) Tashkent 
Indian/Maldives,5,West Asia Standard Time,(UTC+05:00) Tashkent 
Asia/Colombo,5.5,Sri Lanka Standard Time,(UTC+05:30) Sri Jayawardenepura
Asia/Kolkata,5.5,India Standard Time,"(UTC+05:30) Chennai, Kolkata, Mumbai, New Delhi"
Asia/Kathmandu,5.75,Nepal Standard Time,(UTC+05:45) Kathmandu
Antarctica/Mawson,6,Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+06:00) Astana
Asia/Almaty,6,Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+06:00) Astana
Asia/Bishkek,6,Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+06:00) Astana
Asia/Dhaka,6,Bangladesh Standard Time,(UTC+06:00) Dhaka
Asia/Qyzylorda,6,Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+06:00) Astana
Asia/Thimphu,6,Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+06:00) Astana
Asia/Yekaterinburg,6,Ekaterinburg Standard Time,(UTC+06:00) Ekaterinburg
Indian/Chagos,6,Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+06:00) Astana
Asia/Rangoon,6.5,Myanmar Standard Time,(UTC+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)
Indian/Cocos,6.5,Myanmar Standard Time,(UTC+06:30) Yangon (Rangoon)
Antarctica/Davis,7,SE Asia Standard Time,"(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
Asia/Bangkok,7,SE Asia Standard Time,"(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh,7,SE Asia Standard Time,"(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
Asia/Hovd,7,N. Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+07:00) Novosibirsk
Asia/Jakarta,7,SE Asia Standard Time,"(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
Asia/Novokuznetsk,7,N. Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+07:00) Novosibirsk
Asia/Novosibirsk,7,N. Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+07:00) Novosibirsk
Asia/Omsk,7,N. Central Asia Standard Time,(UTC+07:00) Novosibirsk
Asia/Phnom_Penh,7,SE Asia Standard Time,"(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
Asia/Pontianak,7,SE Asia Standard Time,"(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
Asia/Vientiane,7,SE Asia Standard Time,"(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
Indian/Christmas,7,SE Asia Standard Time,"(UTC+07:00) Bangkok, Hanoi, Jakarta"
Antarctica/Casey,8,W. Australia Standard Time,(UTC+08:00) Perth
Asia/Brunei,8,North Asia Standard Time,(UTC+08:00) Krasnoyarsk
Asia/Choibalsan,8,China Standard Time,"(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi"
Asia/Chongqing,8,China Standard Time,"(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi"
Asia/Harbin,8,China Standard Time,"(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi"
Asia/Hong_Kong,8,China Standard Time,"(UTC+08:00) Beijing, Chongqing, Hong Kong, Urumqi"
.... Cut ....
```

Had to cut due to restrictions on post size - get the full CSV at the linked address.

Answer (score 3):

I converted the XML http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml to JSON at https://github.com/uddhav/tzid-from-geo/blob/master/olson_to_windows.json. 430 in all.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with a static table is that it has to be maintained as changes to the TZDB and CLDR are released.

The better solution is to use a library that can do the conversions for you, and will stay on top of the updates for you.

[Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) is the perfect choice for this.  I have already documented how to convert between IANA/Olson and Windows time zones in this post:  [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824)

As new updates to the TZDB and CLDR are released, you can simply get the latest version of Noda Time, or you can update it manually by following the instructions [here](http://nodatime.org/1.1.x/userguide/tzdb.html).

Comment: At the time I put the table together I didn't know about Noda Time, and would certainly have used it if I had.  Saying that, the table has still been pretty useful over the last couple of years.

Comment: Agreed.  And actually, Noda Time was just in the early phases then, and didn't have the full CLDR data until recently.  So yours was a good solution for the time, but I thought I should provide a more updated answer for those that find this post linked to other questions.

Comment: Indeed, this info should definitely be here and its great that a maintained library now includes this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed this mapping for a c++ application.  The unicode mapping covers most of the zones but there are a few issues.

First, many of the olson/tz ids have aliases.  The ids used in the unicode mapping do not include these aliases.  For a more complete mapping your application needs to also understand aliases.

The following defines olson/tz aliases:  http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/bcp47/timezone.xml

For example, the unicode mapping has no definition for 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires', but looking in the above file we see that 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires' is in fact an alias for 'America/Buenos_Aires' which does exist in the mapping file.

Second, there are some olson/tz ids that are not mappable to any Windows time zone.  This can happen because Windows doesn't have a time zone with the same offset or DST rules.  In these cases there really is no conversion possible.  Most of these zones are small islands, so it could be an edge case not worth considering.

For more info on this see:
http://cldr.unicode.org/development/development-process/design-proposals/extended-windows-olson-zid-mapping

Comment: Is your remark about the aliases not existing in the mapping still true? You are referring to the windowsZones.xml file correct? From what I see, there currently is a section for "America/Buenos_Aires" and "America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires". The olson name is duplicated for both entries. The only issue I see remaining are the "Unmappable Olson Time Zones" from the link you provided. These make sense that they don't map and aren't related to the name issue caused by aliases.

Comment: The aliases do not exist in the windowsZones.xml (http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml), but they do exist in timezone.xml (http://www.unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/bcp47/timezone.xml) that I linked to above.  If you search windowsZones.xml for 'Buenos' you'll find 'America/Buenos_Aires', but not 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires'.

Comment: Ok I see now. I saw a group that included America/Buenos_Aires in the "AR" territory and this looked like the aliases.

Answer (score 0):

The comma separated list below consists of these three columns:

**[Windows Time Zone ID],[Region],[Olson TZID]**

Sourced from [Zone to Tzid](http://www.unicode.org/cldr/charts/latest/supplemental/zone_tzid.html) and separated lines with multiple TZID options into individual lines.

**The list:**

```
AUS Central Standard Time,1,Australia/Darwin
AUS Central Standard Time,AU,Australia/Darwin
AUS Eastern Standard Time,1,Australia/Sydney
AUS Eastern Standard Time,AU,Australia/Melbourne
AUS Eastern Standard Time,AU,Australia/Sydney
Afghanistan Standard Time,1,Asia/Kabul
Afghanistan Standard Time,AF,Asia/Kabul
Alaskan Standard Time,1,America/Anchorage
Alaskan Standard Time,US,America/Anchorage
Alaskan Standard Time,US,America/Juneau
Alaskan Standard Time,US,America/Nome
Alaskan Standard Time,US,America/Sitka
Alaskan Standard Time,US,America/Yakutat
Arab Standard Time,1,Asia/Riyadh
Arab Standard Time,BH,Asia/Bahrain
Arab Standard Time,KW,Asia/Kuwait
Arab Standard Time,QA,Asia/Qatar
Arab Standard Time,SA,Asia/Riyadh
Arab Standard Time,YE,Asia/Aden
Arabian Standard Time,1,Asia/Dubai
Arabian Standard Time,AE,Asia/Dubai
Arabian Standard Time,OM,Asia/Muscat
Arabian Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-4
Arabic Standard Time,1,Asia/Baghdad
Arabic Standard Time,IQ,Asia/Baghdad
Argentina Standard Time,1,America/Buenos_Aires
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Mendoza
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Buenos_Aires
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Argentina/Rio_Gallegos
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Argentina/La_Rioja
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Argentina/San_Juan
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Argentina/Salta
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Argentina/Tucuman
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Argentina/San_Luis
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Argentina/Ushuaia
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Catamarca
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Cordoba
Argentina Standard Time,AR,America/Jujuy
Atlantic Standard Time,1,America/Halifax
Atlantic Standard Time,BM,Atlantic/Bermuda
Atlantic Standard Time,CA,America/Moncton
Atlantic Standard Time,CA,America/Halifax
Atlantic Standard Time,CA,America/Glace_Bay
Atlantic Standard Time,CA,America/Goose_Bay
Atlantic Standard Time,GL,America/Thule
Azerbaijan Standard Time,1,Asia/Baku
Azerbaijan Standard Time,AZ,Asia/Baku
Azores Standard Time,1,Atlantic/Azores
Azores Standard Time,GL,America/Scoresbysund
Azores Standard Time,PT,Atlantic/Azores
Bahia Standard Time,1,America/Bahia
Bahia Standard Time,BR,America/Bahia
Bangladesh Standard Time,1,Asia/Dhaka
Bangladesh Standard Time,BD,Asia/Dhaka
Bangladesh Standard Time,BT,Asia/Thimphu
Belarus Standard Time,1,Europe/Minsk
Belarus Standard Time,BY,Europe/Minsk
Canada Central Standard Time,1,America/Regina
Canada Central Standard Time,CA,America/Swift_Current
Canada Central Standard Time,CA,America/Regina
Cape Verde Standard Time,1,Atlantic/Cape_Verde
Cape Verde Standard Time,CV,Atlantic/Cape_Verde
Cape Verde Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT+1
Caucasus Standard Time,1,Asia/Yerevan
Caucasus Standard Time,AM,Asia/Yerevan
Cen. Australia Standard Time,1,Australia/Adelaide
Cen. Australia Standard Time,AU,Australia/Broken_Hill
Cen. Australia Standard Time,AU,Australia/Adelaide
Central America Standard Time,1,America/Guatemala
Central America Standard Time,BZ,America/Belize
Central America Standard Time,CR,America/Costa_Rica
Central America Standard Time,EC,Pacific/Galapagos
Central America Standard Time,GT,America/Guatemala
Central America Standard Time,HN,America/Tegucigalpa
Central America Standard Time,NI,America/Managua
Central America Standard Time,SV,America/El_Salvador
Central America Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT+6
Central Asia Standard Time,1,Asia/Almaty
Central Asia Standard Time,AQ,Antarctica/Vostok
Central Asia Standard Time,CN,Asia/Urumqi
Central Asia Standard Time,IO,Indian/Chagos
Central Asia Standard Time,KG,Asia/Bishkek
Central Asia Standard Time,KZ,Asia/Qyzylorda
Central Asia Standard Time,KZ,Asia/Almaty
Central Asia Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-6
Central Brazilian Standard Time,1,America/Cuiaba
Central Brazilian Standard Time,BR,America/Campo_Grande
Central Brazilian Standard Time,BR,America/Cuiaba
Central Europe Standard Time,1,Europe/Budapest
Central Europe Standard Time,AL,Europe/Tirane
Central Europe Standard Time,CZ,Europe/Prague
Central Europe Standard Time,HU,Europe/Budapest
Central Europe Standard Time,ME,Europe/Podgorica
Central Europe Standard Time,RS,Europe/Belgrade
Central Europe Standard Time,SI,Europe/Ljubljana
Central Europe Standard Time,SK,Europe/Bratislava
Central European Standard Time,1,Europe/Warsaw
Central European Standard Time,BA,Europe/Sarajevo
Central European Standard Time,HR,Europe/Zagreb
Central European Standard Time,MK,Europe/Skopje
Central European Standard Time,PL,Europe/Warsaw
Central Pacific Standard Time,1,Pacific/Guadalcanal
Central Pacific Standard Time,AU,Antarctica/Macquarie
Central Pacific Standard Time,FM,Pacific/Kosrae
Central Pacific Standard Time,FM,Pacific/Ponape
Central Pacific Standard Time,NC,Pacific/Noumea
Central Pacific Standard Time,PG,Pacific/Bougainville
Central Pacific Standard Time,SB,Pacific/Guadalcanal
Central Pacific Standard Time,VU,Pacific/Efate
Central Pacific Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-11
Central Standard Time,1,America/Chicago
Central Standard Time,CA,America/Resolute
Central Standard Time,CA,America/Winnipeg
Central Standard Time,CA,America/Rainy_River
Central Standard Time,CA,America/Rankin_Inlet
Central Standard Time,MX,America/Matamoros
Central Standard Time,US,America/North_Dakota/New_Salem
Central Standard Time,US,America/Chicago
Central Standard Time,US,America/Indiana/Knox
Central Standard Time,US,America/Indiana/Tell_City
Central Standard Time,US,America/Menominee
Central Standard Time,US,America/North_Dakota/Beulah
Central Standard Time,US,America/North_Dakota/Center
Central Standard Time,ZZ,CST6CDT
Central Standard Time (Mexico),1,America/Mexico_City
Central Standard Time (Mexico),MX,America/Monterrey
Central Standard Time (Mexico),MX,America/Mexico_City
Central Standard Time (Mexico),MX,America/Bahia_Banderas
Central Standard Time (Mexico),MX,America/Merida
China Standard Time,1,Asia/Shanghai
China Standard Time,CN,Asia/Shanghai
China Standard Time,HK,Asia/Hong_Kong
China Standard Time,MO,Asia/Macau
Dateline Standard Time,1,Etc/GMT+12
Dateline Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT+12
E. Africa Standard Time,1,Africa/Nairobi
E. Africa Standard Time,AQ,Antarctica/Syowa
E. Africa Standard Time,DJ,Africa/Djibouti
E. Africa Standard Time,ER,Africa/Asmera
E. Africa Standard Time,ET,Africa/Addis_Ababa
E. Africa Standard Time,KE,Africa/Nairobi
E. Africa Standard Time,KM,Indian/Comoro
E. Africa Standard Time,MG,Indian/Antananarivo
E. Africa Standard Time,SD,Africa/Khartoum
E. Africa Standard Time,SO,Africa/Mogadishu
E. Africa Standard Time,SS,Africa/Juba
E. Africa Standard Time,TZ,Africa/Dar_es_Salaam
E. Africa Standard Time,UG,Africa/Kampala
E. Africa Standard Time,YT,Indian/Mayotte
E. Africa Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-3
E. Australia Standard Time,1,Australia/Brisbane
E. Australia Standard Time,AU,Australia/Lindeman
E. Australia Standard Time,AU,Australia/Brisbane
E. South America Standard Time,1,America/Sao_Paulo
E. South America Standard Time,BR,America/Sao_Paulo
Eastern Standard Time,1,America/New_York
Eastern Standard Time,BS,America/Nassau
Eastern Standard Time,CA,America/Thunder_Bay
Eastern Standard Time,CA,America/Toronto
Eastern Standard Time,CA,America/Iqaluit
Eastern Standard Time,CA,America/Montreal
Eastern Standard Time,CA,America/Nipigon
Eastern Standard Time,CA,America/Pangnirtung
Eastern Standard Time,CU,America/Havana
Eastern Standard Time,HT,America/Port-au-Prince
Eastern Standard Time,US,America/Louisville
Eastern Standard Time,US,America/New_York
Eastern Standard Time,US,America/Detroit
Eastern Standard Time,US,America/Indiana/Petersburg
Eastern Standard Time,US,America/Indiana/Vincennes
Eastern Standard Time,US,America/Indiana/Winamac
Eastern Standard Time,US,America/Kentucky/Monticello
Eastern Standard Time,ZZ,EST5EDT
Eastern Standard Time (Mexico),1,America/Cancun
Eastern Standard Time (Mexico),MX,America/Cancun
Egypt Standard Time,1,Africa/Cairo
Egypt Standard Time,EG,Africa/Cairo
Ekaterinburg Standard Time,1,Asia/Yekaterinburg
Ekaterinburg Standard Time,RU,Asia/Yekaterinburg
FLE Standard Time,1,Europe/Kiev
FLE Standard Time,AX,Europe/Mariehamn
FLE Standard Time,BG,Europe/Sofia
FLE Standard Time,EE,Europe/Tallinn
FLE Standard Time,FI,Europe/Helsinki
FLE Standard Time,LT,Europe/Vilnius
FLE Standard Time,LV,Europe/Riga
FLE Standard Time,UA,Europe/Zaporozhye
FLE Standard Time,UA,Europe/Kiev
FLE Standard Time,UA,Europe/Uzhgorod
Fiji Standard Time,1,Pacific/Fiji
Fiji Standard Time,FJ,Pacific/Fiji
GMT Standard Time,1,Europe/London
GMT Standard Time,ES,Atlantic/Canary
GMT Standard Time,FO,Atlantic/Faeroe
GMT Standard Time,GB,Europe/London
GMT Standard Time,GG,Europe/Guernsey
GMT Standard Time,IE,Europe/Dublin
GMT Standard Time,IM,Europe/Isle_of_Man
GMT Standard Time,JE,Europe/Jersey
GMT Standard Time,PT,Atlantic/Madeira
GMT Standard Time,PT,Europe/Lisbon
GTB Standard Time,1,Europe/Bucharest
GTB Standard Time,CY,Asia/Nicosia
GTB Standard Time,GR,Europe/Athens
GTB Standard Time,MD,Europe/Chisinau
GTB Standard Time,RO,Europe/Bucharest
Georgian Standard Time,1,Asia/Tbilisi
Georgian Standard Time,GE,Asia/Tbilisi
Greenland Standard Time,1,America/Godthab
Greenland Standard Time,GL,America/Godthab
Greenwich Standard Time,1,Atlantic/Reykjavik
Greenwich Standard Time,BF,Africa/Ouagadougou
Greenwich Standard Time,CI,Africa/Abidjan
Greenwich Standard Time,GH,Africa/Accra
Greenwich Standard Time,GM,Africa/Banjul
Greenwich Standard Time,GN,Africa/Conakry
Greenwich Standard Time,GW,Africa/Bissau
Greenwich Standard Time,IS,Atlantic/Reykjavik
Greenwich Standard Time,LR,Africa/Monrovia
Greenwich Standard Time,ML,Africa/Bamako
Greenwich Standard Time,MR,Africa/Nouakchott
Greenwich Standard Time,SH,Atlantic/St_Helena
Greenwich Standard Time,SL,Africa/Freetown
Greenwich Standard Time,SN,Africa/Dakar
Greenwich Standard Time,ST,Africa/Sao_Tome
Greenwich Standard Time,TG,Africa/Lome
Hawaiian Standard Time,1,Pacific/Honolulu
Hawaiian Standard Time,CK,Pacific/Rarotonga
Hawaiian Standard Time,PF,Pacific/Tahiti
Hawaiian Standard Time,UM,Pacific/Johnston
Hawaiian Standard Time,US,Pacific/Honolulu
Hawaiian Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT+10
India Standard Time,1,Asia/Calcutta
India Standard Time,IN,Asia/Calcutta
Iran Standard Time,1,Asia/Tehran
Iran Standard Time,IR,Asia/Tehran
Israel Standard Time,1,Asia/Jerusalem
Israel Standard Time,IL,Asia/Jerusalem
Jordan Standard Time,1,Asia/Amman
Jordan Standard Time,JO,Asia/Amman
Kaliningrad Standard Time,1,Europe/Kaliningrad
Kaliningrad Standard Time,RU,Europe/Kaliningrad
Korea Standard Time,1,Asia/Seoul
Korea Standard Time,KR,Asia/Seoul
Libya Standard Time,1,Africa/Tripoli
Libya Standard Time,LY,Africa/Tripoli
Line Islands Standard Time,1,Pacific/Kiritimati
Line Islands Standard Time,KI,Pacific/Kiritimati
Line Islands Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-14
Magadan Standard Time,1,Asia/Magadan
Magadan Standard Time,RU,Asia/Magadan
Mauritius Standard Time,1,Indian/Mauritius
Mauritius Standard Time,MU,Indian/Mauritius
Mauritius Standard Time,RE,Indian/Reunion
Mauritius Standard Time,SC,Indian/Mahe
Middle East Standard Time,1,Asia/Beirut
Middle East Standard Time,LB,Asia/Beirut
Montevideo Standard Time,1,America/Montevideo
Montevideo Standard Time,UY,America/Montevideo
Morocco Standard Time,1,Africa/Casablanca
Morocco Standard Time,EH,Africa/El_Aaiun
Morocco Standard Time,MA,Africa/Casablanca
Mountain Standard Time,1,America/Denver
Mountain Standard Time,CA,America/Yellowknife
Mountain Standard Time,CA,America/Edmonton
Mountain Standard Time,CA,America/Cambridge_Bay
Mountain Standard Time,CA,America/Inuvik
Mountain Standard Time,MX,America/Ojinaga
Mountain Standard Time,US,America/Boise
Mountain Standard Time,US,America/Denver
Mountain Standard Time,ZZ,MST7MDT
Mountain Standard Time (Mexico),1,America/Chihuahua
Mountain Standard Time (Mexico),MX,America/Mazatlan
Mountain Standard Time (Mexico),MX,America/Chihuahua
Myanmar Standard Time,1,Asia/Rangoon
Myanmar Standard Time,CC,Indian/Cocos
Myanmar Standard Time,MM,Asia/Rangoon
N. Central Asia Standard Time,1,Asia/Novosibirsk
N. Central Asia Standard Time,RU,Asia/Omsk
N. Central Asia Standard Time,RU,Asia/Novosibirsk
Namibia Standard Time,1,Africa/Windhoek
Namibia Standard Time,NA,Africa/Windhoek
Nepal Standard Time,1,Asia/Katmandu
Nepal Standard Time,NP,Asia/Katmandu
New Zealand Standard Time,1,Pacific/Auckland
New Zealand Standard Time,AQ,Antarctica/McMurdo
New Zealand Standard Time,NZ,Pacific/Auckland
Newfoundland Standard Time,1,America/St_Johns
Newfoundland Standard Time,CA,America/St_Johns
North Asia East Standard Time,1,Asia/Irkutsk
North Asia East Standard Time,RU,Asia/Chita
North Asia East Standard Time,RU,Asia/Irkutsk
North Asia Standard Time,1,Asia/Krasnoyarsk
North Asia Standard Time,RU,Asia/Novokuznetsk
North Asia Standard Time,RU,Asia/Krasnoyarsk
Pacific SA Standard Time,1,America/Santiago
Pacific SA Standard Time,AQ,Antarctica/Palmer
Pacific SA Standard Time,CL,America/Santiago
Pacific Standard Time,1,America/Los_Angeles
Pacific Standard Time,CA,America/Whitehorse
Pacific Standard Time,CA,America/Vancouver
Pacific Standard Time,CA,America/Dawson
Pacific Standard Time,MX,America/Tijuana
Pacific Standard Time,US,America/Los_Angeles
Pacific Standard Time,ZZ,PST8PDT
Pacific Standard Time (Mexico),1,America/Santa_Isabel
Pacific Standard Time (Mexico),MX,America/Santa_Isabel
Pakistan Standard Time,1,Asia/Karachi
Pakistan Standard Time,PK,Asia/Karachi
Paraguay Standard Time,1,America/Asuncion
Paraguay Standard Time,PY,America/Asuncion
Romance Standard Time,1,Europe/Paris
Romance Standard Time,BE,Europe/Brussels
Romance Standard Time,DK,Europe/Copenhagen
Romance Standard Time,ES,Africa/Ceuta
Romance Standard Time,ES,Europe/Madrid
Romance Standard Time,FR,Europe/Paris
Russia Time Zone 10,1,Asia/Srednekolymsk
Russia Time Zone 10,RU,Asia/Srednekolymsk
Russia Time Zone 11,1,Asia/Kamchatka
Russia Time Zone 11,RU,Asia/Anadyr
Russia Time Zone 11,RU,Asia/Kamchatka
Russia Time Zone 3,1,Europe/Samara
Russia Time Zone 3,RU,Europe/Samara
Russian Standard Time,1,Europe/Moscow
Russian Standard Time,RU,Europe/Volgograd
Russian Standard Time,RU,Europe/Moscow
Russian Standard Time,RU,Europe/Simferopol
SA Eastern Standard Time,1,America/Cayenne
SA Eastern Standard Time,AQ,Antarctica/Rothera
SA Eastern Standard Time,BR,America/Santarem
SA Eastern Standard Time,BR,America/Fortaleza
SA Eastern Standard Time,BR,America/Araguaina
SA Eastern Standard Time,BR,America/Belem
SA Eastern Standard Time,BR,America/Maceio
SA Eastern Standard Time,BR,America/Recife
SA Eastern Standard Time,FK,Atlantic/Stanley
SA Eastern Standard Time,GF,America/Cayenne
SA Eastern Standard Time,SR,America/Paramaribo
SA Eastern Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT+3
SA Pacific Standard Time,1,America/Bogota
SA Pacific Standard Time,BR,America/Eirunepe
SA Pacific Standard Time,BR,America/Rio_Branco
SA Pacific Standard Time,CA,America/Coral_Harbour
SA Pacific Standard Time,CO,America/Bogota
SA Pacific Standard Time,EC,America/Guayaquil
SA Pacific Standard Time,JM,America/Jamaica
SA Pacific Standard Time,KY,America/Cayman
SA Pacific Standard Time,PA,America/Panama
SA Pacific Standard Time,PE,America/Lima
SA Pacific Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT+5
SA Western Standard Time,1,America/La_Paz
SA Western Standard Time,AG,America/Antigua
SA Western Standard Time,AI,America/Anguilla
SA Western Standard Time,AW,America/Aruba
SA Western Standard Time,BB,America/Barbados
SA Western Standard Time,BL,America/St_Barthelemy
SA Western Standard Time,BO,America/La_Paz
SA Western Standard Time,BQ,America/Kralendijk
SA Western Standard Time,BR,America/Porto_Velho
SA Western Standard Time,BR,America/Manaus
SA Western Standard Time,BR,America/Boa_Vista
SA Western Standard Time,CA,America/Blanc-Sablon
SA Western Standard Time,CW,America/Curacao
SA Western Standard Time,DM,America/Dominica
SA Western Standard Time,DO,America/Santo_Domingo
SA Western Standard Time,GD,America/Grenada
SA Western Standard Time,GP,America/Guadeloupe
SA Western Standard Time,GY,America/Guyana
SA Western Standard Time,KN,America/St_Kitts
SA Western Standard Time,LC,America/St_Lucia
SA Western Standard Time,MF,America/Marigot
SA Western Standard Time,MQ,America/Martinique
SA Western Standard Time,MS,America/Montserrat
SA Western Standard Time,PR,America/Puerto_Rico
SA Western Standard Time,SX,America/Lower_Princes
SA Western Standard Time,TC,America/Grand_Turk
SA Western Standard Time,TT,America/Port_of_Spain
SA Western Standard Time,VC,America/St_Vincent
SA Western Standard Time,VG,America/Tortola
SA Western Standard Time,VI,America/St_Thomas
SA Western Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT+4
SE Asia Standard Time,1,Asia/Bangkok
SE Asia Standard Time,AQ,Antarctica/Davis
SE Asia Standard Time,CX,Indian/Christmas
SE Asia Standard Time,ID,Asia/Pontianak
SE Asia Standard Time,ID,Asia/Jakarta
SE Asia Standard Time,KH,Asia/Phnom_Penh
SE Asia Standard Time,LA,Asia/Vientiane
SE Asia Standard Time,MN,Asia/Hovd
SE Asia Standard Time,TH,Asia/Bangkok
SE Asia Standard Time,VN,Asia/Saigon
SE Asia Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-7
Samoa Standard Time,1,Pacific/Apia
Samoa Standard Time,WS,Pacific/Apia
Singapore Standard Time,1,Asia/Singapore
Singapore Standard Time,BN,Asia/Brunei
Singapore Standard Time,ID,Asia/Makassar
Singapore Standard Time,MY,Asia/Kuching
Singapore Standard Time,MY,Asia/Kuala_Lumpur
Singapore Standard Time,PH,Asia/Manila
Singapore Standard Time,SG,Asia/Singapore
Singapore Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-8
South Africa Standard Time,1,Africa/Johannesburg
South Africa Standard Time,BI,Africa/Bujumbura
South Africa Standard Time,BW,Africa/Gaborone
South Africa Standard Time,CD,Africa/Lubumbashi
South Africa Standard Time,LS,Africa/Maseru
South Africa Standard Time,MW,Africa/Blantyre
South Africa Standard Time,MZ,Africa/Maputo
South Africa Standard Time,RW,Africa/Kigali
South Africa Standard Time,SZ,Africa/Mbabane
South Africa Standard Time,ZA,Africa/Johannesburg
South Africa Standard Time,ZM,Africa/Lusaka
South Africa Standard Time,ZW,Africa/Harare
South Africa Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-2
Sri Lanka Standard Time,1,Asia/Colombo
Sri Lanka Standard Time,LK,Asia/Colombo
Syria Standard Time,1,Asia/Damascus
Syria Standard Time,SY,Asia/Damascus
Taipei Standard Time,1,Asia/Taipei
Taipei Standard Time,TW,Asia/Taipei
Tasmania Standard Time,1,Australia/Hobart
Tasmania Standard Time,AU,Australia/Currie
Tasmania Standard Time,AU,Australia/Hobart
Tokyo Standard Time,1,Asia/Tokyo
Tokyo Standard Time,ID,Asia/Jayapura
Tokyo Standard Time,JP,Asia/Tokyo
Tokyo Standard Time,PW,Pacific/Palau
Tokyo Standard Time,TL,Asia/Dili
Tokyo Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-9
Tonga Standard Time,1,Pacific/Tongatapu
Tonga Standard Time,KI,Pacific/Enderbury
Tonga Standard Time,TK,Pacific/Fakaofo
Tonga Standard Time,TO,Pacific/Tongatapu
Tonga Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-13
Turkey Standard Time,1,Europe/Istanbul
Turkey Standard Time,TR,Europe/Istanbul
US Eastern Standard Time,1,America/Indianapolis
US Eastern Standard Time,US,America/Indiana/Vevay
US Eastern Standard Time,US,America/Indianapolis
US Eastern Standard Time,US,America/Indiana/Marengo
US Mountain Standard Time,1,America/Phoenix
US Mountain Standard Time,CA,America/Creston
US Mountain Standard Time,CA,America/Dawson_Creek
US Mountain Standard Time,MX,America/Hermosillo
US Mountain Standard Time,US,America/Phoenix
US Mountain Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT+7
UTC,1,Etc/GMT
UTC,GL,America/Danmarkshavn
UTC,ZZ,Etc/GMT
UTC+12,1,Etc/GMT-12
UTC+12,KI,Pacific/Tarawa
UTC+12,MH,Pacific/Kwajalein
UTC+12,MH,Pacific/Majuro
UTC+12,NR,Pacific/Nauru
UTC+12,TV,Pacific/Funafuti
UTC+12,UM,Pacific/Wake
UTC+12,WF,Pacific/Wallis
UTC+12,ZZ,Etc/GMT-12
UTC-02,1,Etc/GMT+2
UTC-02,BR,America/Noronha
UTC-02,GS,Atlantic/South_Georgia
UTC-02,ZZ,Etc/GMT+2
UTC-11,1,Etc/GMT+11
UTC-11,AS,Pacific/Pago_Pago
UTC-11,NU,Pacific/Niue
UTC-11,UM,Pacific/Midway
UTC-11,ZZ,Etc/GMT+11
Ulaanbaatar Standard Time,1,Asia/Ulaanbaatar
Ulaanbaatar Standard Time,MN,Asia/Choibalsan
Ulaanbaatar Standard Time,MN,Asia/Ulaanbaatar
Venezuela Standard Time,1,America/Caracas
Venezuela Standard Time,VE,America/Caracas
Vladivostok Standard Time,1,Asia/Vladivostok
Vladivostok Standard Time,RU,Asia/Ust-Nera
Vladivostok Standard Time,RU,Asia/Vladivostok
Vladivostok Standard Time,RU,Asia/Sakhalin
W. Australia Standard Time,1,Australia/Perth
W. Australia Standard Time,AQ,Antarctica/Casey
W. Australia Standard Time,AU,Australia/Perth
W. Central Africa Standard Time,1,Africa/Lagos
W. Central Africa Standard Time,AO,Africa/Luanda
W. Central Africa Standard Time,BJ,Africa/Porto-Novo
W. Central Africa Standard Time,CD,Africa/Kinshasa
W. Central Africa Standard Time,CF,Africa/Bangui
W. Central Africa Standard Time,CG,Africa/Brazzaville
W. Central Africa Standard Time,CM,Africa/Douala
W. Central Africa Standard Time,DZ,Africa/Algiers
W. Central Africa Standard Time,GA,Africa/Libreville
W. Central Africa Standard Time,GQ,Africa/Malabo
W. Central Africa Standard Time,NE,Africa/Niamey
W. Central Africa Standard Time,NG,Africa/Lagos
W. Central Africa Standard Time,TD,Africa/Ndjamena
W. Central Africa Standard Time,TN,Africa/Tunis
W. Central Africa Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-1
W. Europe Standard Time,1,Europe/Berlin
W. Europe Standard Time,AD,Europe/Andorra
W. Europe Standard Time,AT,Europe/Vienna
W. Europe Standard Time,CH,Europe/Zurich
W. Europe Standard Time,DE,Europe/Busingen
W. Europe Standard Time,DE,Europe/Berlin
W. Europe Standard Time,GI,Europe/Gibraltar
W. Europe Standard Time,IT,Europe/Rome
W. Europe Standard Time,LI,Europe/Vaduz
W. Europe Standard Time,LU,Europe/Luxembourg
W. Europe Standard Time,MC,Europe/Monaco
W. Europe Standard Time,MT,Europe/Malta
W. Europe Standard Time,NL,Europe/Amsterdam
W. Europe Standard Time,NO,Europe/Oslo
W. Europe Standard Time,SE,Europe/Stockholm
W. Europe Standard Time,SJ,Arctic/Longyearbyen
W. Europe Standard Time,SM,Europe/San_Marino
W. Europe Standard Time,VA,Europe/Vatican
West Asia Standard Time,1,Asia/Tashkent
West Asia Standard Time,AQ,Antarctica/Mawson
West Asia Standard Time,KZ,Asia/Aqtobe
West Asia Standard Time,KZ,Asia/Oral
West Asia Standard Time,KZ,Asia/Aqtau
West Asia Standard Time,MV,Indian/Maldives
West Asia Standard Time,TF,Indian/Kerguelen
West Asia Standard Time,TJ,Asia/Dushanbe
West Asia Standard Time,TM,Asia/Ashgabat
West Asia Standard Time,UZ,Asia/Samarkand
West Asia Standard Time,UZ,Asia/Tashkent
West Asia Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-5
West Pacific Standard Time,1,Pacific/Port_Moresby
West Pacific Standard Time,AQ,Antarctica/DumontDUrville
West Pacific Standard Time,FM,Pacific/Truk
West Pacific Standard Time,GU,Pacific/Guam
West Pacific Standard Time,MP,Pacific/Saipan
West Pacific Standard Time,PG,Pacific/Port_Moresby
West Pacific Standard Time,ZZ,Etc/GMT-10
Yakutsk Standard Time,1,Asia/Yakutsk
Yakutsk Standard Time,RU,Asia/Khandyga
Yakutsk Standard Time,RU,Asia/Yakutsk
```