# Finding transition date/times from standard to daylight savings and vice-versa in CoreFoundation

Tags: c++, macos, datetime, timezone, core-foundation

I'm trying to replicate the functionality of the Windows function [GetTimeZoneInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms724421%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which populates a [TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms725481%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure, using CoreFoundation. I've made a function that turns a `CFAbsoluteTime` along with a `CFTimeZoneRef` into the equivalent of a `SYSTEMTIME`, but there are a few other things I can't quite figure out. For example:

- `StandardDate` and `DaylightDate`: I've used the `CFTimeZoneGetNextDaylightSavingTimeTransition` function to find the next transition, and `CFTimeZoneIsDaylightSavingTime` to determine which transition this is, but since `TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION` requires both dates, how  would I find the transition *after* the next transition?
- Similarly, `DaylightBias` - I can use `CFTimeZoneGetDaylightSavingTimeOffset` to find the offset if we're currently in DST, but this value goes to zero if we're not currently in DST. I know it's pretty much always -60, but I'd like this function to stay completely faithful to the Windows function.

Does anyone know a good solution for this?

Comment: Can you use managed code?  [.Net's `TimeZoneInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.aspx?cs-lang=cpp) has everything set up quite well.   Wait a sec, I see you tagged OSX, but you are talking about windows stuff?  I'm confused.  Please clarify.

Comment: Also, Windows uses the Microsoft Timezone database, which is completely different than the IANA/Olson database used by the rest of the world (unix, linux, mac osx).  You will probably have a hard time  making it conform.  I know little about osx programming, but I found [this reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimeZone_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSTimeZone) which may help you do it the mac way properly.

Comment: I'm porting something from Windows to Mac, so need to make it conform to the standard. I think I've come up with something pretty solid (I'll post an answer when I've tested a bit more), but it's going to be hard to cover all the edge cases. Thanks for the heads up about the timezone database - I didn't realise that Windows used a different one! Talk about reinventing the wheel...

Comment: Yep.  It's a sore point for interoperability.  If the program you are porting runs entirely on the mac, I would use the stuff that comes built in with osx - including their time zones.  If you need to interop with windows machines, then you will need some code to map between them.  One way mappings from Windows to IANA/Olson are in the CLDR [here](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml).  Going the other direction is nearly impossible.  Others have [tried](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372537/converting-olson-tzid-to-windows-time-zone), but its a hack.