# moment.js, timezones and daylight savings

Tags: javascript, timezone, dst, momentjs, timezone-offset

I return a list of UTC dates/times from a .Net service, formatted like so:

```
"2013-07-09 19:48:07 +00:00".
```

On the client, I convert each of these string values into a corresponding UTC-based moment, like so

```
var fooUtc = new moment.utc(serverDateTimeString)
```

On the page, there is a droop-down containing a list of time-zones that the user can change.  These are tied to a collection of time-zone objects like the following:

```
{
    id: "Central Standard Time",
    label: "(UTC-06:00) Central Time (US & Canada)",
    observesDaylightSavings: true,
    baseUtcOffset: {
        asHours: -6,
        asMinutes: -360,
        asText: "-06:00"
}
```

I then display each moment passing in the selected time-zone offset, like so:

```
fooUtc.local().zone(selectedTimeZone.baseUtcOffset.asMinutes).format()
```

However, the result does not take into account daylight savings, as the timezone data coming from .Net does not differentiate between dst and non dst offsets.

Is there a way to make this work with moment.js or the new moment-timezone bits?  I think it could be possible if I could map the standard UTC offset names (ex:  "Central Standard Time") to a given timezone's [Olson](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database) DB identifier (ex: "America/Chicago"), but if there is an easier way, please let me know.

Comment: I ended up creating a mapper file based on the [this post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372537/converting-olson-tzid-to-windows-time-zone

Answer (score 6):

You should explore using [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org) on the .Net side, and [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) on the client, passing the IANA/Olson time zone id.

If you want to stick to the Windows time zone ids in your drop-down list, then you can do conversions with the CLDR data embedded in Noda Time.  I have documented how to do it in this post:  [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17348807/634824)

But the better solution would be to avoid the Windows zones all together.  You can populate a list of IANA/Olson ids using the technique I describe in this post:  [How should I populate a list of IANA / Olson time zones from Noda Time?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13056759/634824)

Better yet, you can replace your drop-down list with a control (inline or modal) that displays a map of the world, so your users can easily select their time zone.  The best control for this that I have seen is [this one](https://github.com/dosx/timezone-picker), but there are a few others out there also.

If you can deal strictly in IANA/Olson zones, then there's no need for conversion.  You can give up the Windows `TimeZoneInfo` object and just use Noda Time instead.  If you want, you can replace just your time zone conversion functions and leave the rest intact.  Or, you could go all-out and replace all of your `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` uses with Noda Time types.  It's up to you.

Comment: that would be nice, but the user preferences are stored in the DB using the timezone id, so I'm stuck with it for now.  Thanks for the heads-up on Noda... I'll take a look...