# Can't change timezone with angular-moment

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs, angular-moment

I am using Angular.js with [angular-moment](https://github.com/urish/angular-moment) and I am trying to display a date in a different timezone:

```
p(style="font-size: 70%",am-time-ago="thing.date")
```

I am including moment.js, as well as the moment.js timezone data ([this file](http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data-2010-2020.min.js)). In my .html file:

```
  <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
  <script src="bower_components/moment-timezone/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```

I have also added the configuration in the Angular.js file, as it says on the angular-moment Github page:

```
angular.module('myApp')
  .constant('angularMomentConfig', { timezone: 'America/New_York' })
```

I have tried quite a couple of permutations up to now, but nothing seems to work. I have no idea what I might be doing wrong, so any suggestion is more than welcome.

Comment: Hmmm. "I have tried a lot [..] and nothing works" is obfruscating the most valuable thing: what is wrong with the code and what you know that is NOT the cause. Helps in guessing what is happening, when no stacktrace is given.

Comment: @mico: I do agree that, in general, that would be more helpful, but I have no idea where things could go wrong. That is why I am asking for suggestions, just  things that maybe I could check. My level of Angular is not that great, and I have never used moment.js before, so I have no idea how everything should fit together. I am quite sure that I have followed the docs, but I keep thinking that maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Could you tell, what it does instead of showing the time you want?

Comment: It displays a date in the future, even though the time is in the past. So for example, if the date is 19:00 and the current time is 19:10, it will say something like "in an hour" even though it should say "10 minutes ago". I am assuming that the issue has something to do with the default timezone, but I can't change it, hence this question.

Comment: Yes, my first action would be to be sure which timezone the thing.date is and after that see how it relates to new_york time zone.

Comment: Please show some actual data examples.  Time "ago" has little to do with time zones, but you might be *parsing* the data in a way that does.

Comment: For example, I have the date `2015-04-07T00:36:29.000Z` in my `thing.date` field which is used as shown in the post above ^. The current hour is 00:43, but moment.js outputs `is an hour`, instead of `6 minutes ago`. I do nothing special to that date, simply doing `console.log(thing.date)` outputs `2015-04-07T00:36:29.000Z`.

Answer (score 1):

You say to use angular-moments.js but are not including the angular-moments.js itself to your code.

Look instructions from https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-momentjs , there the suggestion is to use bower and npm with the following commands:

> You can download angular-momentjs by:
>
> - (preferred) Using bower and running bower install angular-momentjs --save
> - Using npm and running npm install angular-momentjs --save

and the result would be:

```
 <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.5.1/moment.min.js"></script>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.min.js"></script>

 <script src="app/bower_components/angular-momentjs/angular-momentjs.js"></script>
```

Comment: Sorry, the issue that I can't change the timezone, it does display a valid string though saying "10 minutes ago" or similar.

Comment: Could it relate to inconsistent daylightsaving issue like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17559726/moment-js-timezones-and-daylight-savings ? DayLightSaving (DST) needs to be handled separately in some casea with isDST( ) function like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918095/moment-js-how-to-detect-daylight-savings-time-and-add-one-day

Comment: Hmm, I assume that even if it was, it would still have to change the time shown from "in 1 hour" to, for example, "4 hours ago". The problem I have is that the "distance" to that date doesn't change no matter what timezone I attach to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. Wandered to this question trying to find solution. So Here it is if someone else wanders here too looking for same answer.

Since version 1.0.0-beta.1, time zone can be set using **amMoment** service. Just inject the amMoment service and call changeTimeZone:

```
amMoment.changeTimezone('Europe/London');
```