# Get all timezones

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I am trying to get all the timezones. What I have done is:

`$tzlist = DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers(DateTimeZone::ALL);`

It gives me an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Africa/Abidjan
    [1] => Africa/Accra
    [2] => Africa/Addis_Ababa
    [3] => Africa/Algiers
    [4] => Africa/Asmara
    [5] => Africa/Bamako
    [6] => Africa/Bangui
    [7] => Africa/Banjul
    [8] => Africa/Bissau....
```

I want to change the timezone name to full timezone name for all timezones
e.g.

```
Australia/Darwin = AUS Central Standard Time
```

You can see the example [here](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zones/)

Comment: Please comment who are downvoting the question so i can improve the same

Comment: I didn't downvote, but what is the question/problem?

Comment: @Andreas I want time zone like `Australia/Darwin` full name  as `AUS Central Standard Time` for all the timezones

Comment: I think that the downvote is because you don't explain your exact problem, only "what you want". What you tried? What's your code after the $tzlist? Did you want to select `Australia/Darwin` in the array or do you want to change `Australia/Darwin` to `AUS Central...`? Try to post your exact problem and what you have searched / tried (and the code!)

Comment: @JP.Aulet I think now the question is clear, But i didn't find any useful code to post with the question

Comment: The problem is that the full name for a lot of timezones derived using the `IntlTimeZone` object in the PHP `intl` module is `GMT` with an offset, which for a page with worldwide usage would be very cryptic for many users. At least with the official names, they have a city name that they likely know is in their time zone. Also, the time zone is the current one, which may be summer time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`IntlTimeZone::getDisplayName()`](http://php.net/manual/en/intltimezone.getdisplayname.php), e.g.:

```
echo IntlTimeZone::createTimeZone("Australia/Darwin")->getDisplayName();
```

Outputs:

```
Australian Central Standard Time
```

Though many will change throughout the year for daylight saving. If you want to check for this and add the alternate daylight/summer display name you can do something like:

```
$tz = IntlTimeZone::createTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
echo $tz->getDisplayName(), "\n";
if ($tz->useDaylightTime()) {
    echo $tz->getDisplayName(true);
}
```

which outputs:

```
Pacific Standard Time
Pacific Daylight Time
```

Comment: Thats the answer I was looking for :)

Comment: @PradeepSingh - are you sure?  In [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45521276/get-all-timezones#comment78003673_45521624) you confirmed you wanted windows IDs.  That is different than these locale-specific display names (which come from CLDR).  Which is it??

Comment: @MattJohnson Yes, I want the same but I was not confirm what to name that, when I found that windows Ids looks same as I want I asked for that

Comment: Note that `getDisplayName` produces `GMT` followed by an offset for many canonical (non-deprecated) time zones, which may be more confusing than the ID for users in some time zones.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking are IDs of Microsoft Windows time zones ([here](http://unicode.org/repos/cldr/trunk/common/supplemental/windowsZones.xml)). PHP uses IANA/Olson time zones. See the [timezone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for details.

From [PHP official documentation](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php#84459), you can try this:

```
<?php

$timezones = DateTimeZone::listAbbreviations();

$cities = array();
foreach( $timezones as $key => $zones )
{
    foreach( $zones as $id => $zone )
    {
        /**
         * Only get timezones explicitely not part of "Others".
         * @see http://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.others.php
         */
        if ( preg_match( '/^(America|Antartica|Arctic|Asia|Atlantic|Europe|Indian|Pacific)\//', $zone['timezone_id'] ) )
            $cities[$zone['timezone_id']][] = $key;
    }
}

// For each city, have a comma separated list of all possible timezones for that city.
foreach( $cities as $key => $value )
    $cities[$key] = join( ', ', $value);

// Only keep one city (the first and also most important) for each set of possibilities. 
$cities = array_unique( $cities );

// Sort by area/city name.
ksort( $cities );

?>
```

Here another SO question that you can look, there are lots of similar answers: [Generating a drop down list of timezones with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727077/generating-a-drop-down-list-of-timezones-with-php)

If none of this helps, you can try the above code, to `convert` the data to your timezone. For example let us assume we have a UTC date and time string (2017-08-05 02:45) that we would like to convert to ACST (Australian Central Standard Time).

```
<?php
$utc_date = DateTime::createFromFormat(
    'Y-m-d G:i',
    '2017-08-05 02:45',
    new DateTimeZone('UTC')
);

$acst_date = clone $utc_date; // we don't want PHP's default pass object by reference here
$acst_date->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Australia/Yancowinna'));

echo 'UTC:  ' . $utc_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A');  // UTC:  2017-08-05 02:45 AM
echo 'ACST: ' . $acst_date->format('Y-m-d g:i A'); // ACST: 2017-08-05  14:15 PM
```

Hope it helps!

**UPDATE:**

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372537/converting-olson-tzid-to-windows-time-zone), you have a Windows ids timezone to PHP:

AUS Central Standard Time,1,Australia/Darwin
AUS Central Standard Time,AU,Australia/Darwin
AUS Eastern Standard Time,1,Australia/Sydney
AUS Eastern Standard Time,AU,Australia/Melbourne
AUS Eastern Standard Time,AU,Australia/Sydney

change to a php array:

```
$timezonesArray = 
['AUS Central Standard Time','1','Australia/Darwin',
'AUS Central Standard Time','AU','Australia/Darwin',
'AUS Eastern Standard Time','1','Australia/Sydney',
'AUS Eastern Standard Time','AU','Australia/Melbourne',
'AUS Eastern Standard Time','AU','Australia/Sydney',
'Afghanistan Standard Time','1','Asia/Kabul',
'Afghanistan Standard Time','AF','Asia/Kabul',,
'Alaskan Standard Time','1','America/Anchorage',
'Alaskan Standard Time','US','America/Anchorage',
'Alaskan Standard Time','US','America/Juneau',
'Alaskan Standard Time','US','America/Nome',
'Alaskan Standard Time','US','America/Sitka',
'Alaskan Standard Time','US','America/Yakutat']; 
//... the array continues
```

and then you can make a function to translate your timezone (array position 2) with your desired windows id (array position[0]), with find or whatever you want.

It's a not the more elegant solution I guess but it will work and its simple. You can search over the array and return the required `translation` from one codification to the other.

Hope it helps now, happy coding!

Comment: Yes @JP.Aulet, I want IDs of windows time zone, so I can get them in a array like `Australia/Darwin => AUS Central Standard Time
Australia/Melbourne => AUS Eastern Standard Time
Australia/Sydney => AUS Eastern Standard Time
Asia/Kabul  => Afghanistan Standard Time
America/Anchorage => Alaskan Standard Time`