# Cross-platform timezone serialization

Tags: serialization, time, timezone, cross-platform, iana

I need to save timezones - along with other data - to a file and read the file from multiple platforms (Linux, WinRT, Windows Phone 8, OS X, Android, iOS). Likely languages are C++, C#, Java, and Objective-C.

Saving the timezone offset as a double is insufficient for my needs, because this loses daylight savings information, which is important. Depending on the date and the timezone, 2 am + 2 hours could be 3 am, 4 am, or 5 am.

Is there a universally supported serializable timezone format?

Comment: I am not sure if you need something different than ISO 8601. Do you need to store the time, or are you only concerned about timezone offset ?

Comment: Neither. Timezones have a dynamic offset, which in the case of daylight savings changes twice a year. That's why - if feasible - I want to save the timezone, not just the static timezone offset. A single-platform approach for this is to use the `TimeZoneInfo` class in .NET.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, timezones do not have dynamic offset. But country/region switches between timezones for daylight saving. For instance, my country uses EET (UTC+2) for winter, and EEST (UTC+3) for summer.

Comment: I'm referring to Timezone as a concept as implemented here:
http://userguide.icu-project.org/datetime/timezone and here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems the best answer is to use [IANA](http://www.iana.org/time-zones)/Olson/TZDB time zones (which are supported on the Unix based systems), and convert them for the Windows-based platforms. 2-way conversion seems to be unreliable, so the most feasible option seems to be to replace the default datetime framework in .NET with [NodaTime](http://nodatime.org), as described in multiple related questions:

- [Time Zone Mapping from iPad (Objective C) to MVP Web API (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21154470/time-zone-mapping-from-ipad-objective-c-to-mvp-web-api-c/21155603#21155603)
- [How to translate between Windows and IANA time zones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17348807/how-to-translate-between-windows-and-iana-time-zones)
- [Converting Olson TZID to Windows Time Zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8372537/converting-olson-tzid-to-windows-time-zone)
- [How to convert a time zone information in C# to a time zone information in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12087083/how-to-convert-a-time-zone-information-in-c-sharp-to-a-time-zone-information-in)

Comment: Yes.  You are correct.  See also: [Proper way to store a timezone in a database?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15824482/634824), which is coming from a different perspective, but is similar in nature.