# How to Convert From Specific Time Zone to UTC

Tags: c#

there is a method to get the user's time zone that returns something like this: `America/New York`, or `Asia/Bangkok` and so on...

Is there a method in C# I could use to convert dates from the user's time zone time zone to UTC?

All the data in our database is stored in UTC, and I need to translate the date requests to UTC to accurately check the database for the right results.

Comment: Are the "dates from the user's time zone" `DateTime`? `string`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15194524/how-to-convert-a-time-and-olson-timezone-to-the-time-in-another-olson-timezone

Comment: @HansPassant this is what I was looking for! thank you so much!