# What's the equivalent in C# of TimeZone.getDefault().getID() in Java?

Tags: c#, java, timezone, jodatime, nodatime

For one lives in [Republic of Molossia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Republic_of_Molossia), the following code in Java:

```
String TimeZoneId=TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
System.out.println(TimeZoneId);
```

will print

> America/Regina

I tried `TimeZoneInfo.GetSystemTimeZones()` but the return value doesn't seem a tzdb id. Is there an equivalent method in C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

.Net does not natievely support the TZDB, because Microsoft has it's own time zone database.  See the [TimeZone tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info) for details.

If you want to work with TZDB zones, use the [NodaTime](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) library.  The exact translation of what you asked is:

```
using NodaTime;

...

var timeZoneId = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault().Id;
Console.WriteLine(timeZoneId);
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically this can be done using the TimeZone class. This is the closest that you will get with the native libraries from my understanding. Why do you need that specific result?

Take a look at [Microsoft Time Zones](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973627) and the Conversion Table* for the Windows Equivalent as Windows does not fully support the TZID, take a look at the stack overflow question below for more information. I hope this is more useful as I misread your previous question!!! - sorry!

```
//Get A reference to our timezone object
TimeZone t = TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone;

//Print out the display name
Console.WriteLine(t.StandardName);
```

[MSDN REFERENCE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xe5cd9e6(v=vs.80).aspx)

http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/zone_tzid.html

Please refer this previous stackoverflow question
[.NET TimeZoneInfo from Olson time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996320/net-timezoneinfo-from-olson-time-zone)

Comment: See update, changed the information. What is it you want to achieve with this, maybe there is another way?

Comment: @HassanGhoncheh - Don't confuse the names with the ids.  And `TimeZone` is mostly deprecated in favor of `TimeZoneInfo`.  To get the id of the current Windows time zone, use `TimeZoneInfo.Local.Id`.

Answer (score 1):

Similar value is returned by

```
Calendar.GetTimeZone
```

for more information: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.globalization.calendar.gettimezone?view=winrt-20348