# GMT DateTime Conversion between different TimeZones

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, datetime, .net-4.0

Web application is hosted on a server with (UTC+10.00)Canberra,Sydney,Melbourne TimeZone. When a user from Melbourne creates an event it saves the datetime to database in GMT format.

> if the user selection is 23/12/2015 3:30:00 AM value saved to the DB
>   will be 2015-12-22 16:30:00.000

Now when a user from (UTC+10.00)Brisbane visits the application it's still shows the same datetime but they are one hour behind from Melbourne time. So they are suppose to view

> 23/12/2015 2:30:00 AM

There could be users from different parts of Australia. How to convert this datetime to logged in users TimeZone?

Answer (score 1):

Check this.

```
TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(date);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(v=vs.110).aspx

[Convert UTC/GMT time to local time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/179940/convert-utc-gmt-time-to-local-time)

Answer (score 0):

You can get the timezone offset from the clients browser using Javascript.

```
function returnTimeDiff(postDateTime, spanid) {
    var offset =(new Date().getTimezoneOffset() / 60)
}
```

[Convert UTC time to Client browser's timezone using JavaScript in a MVC View](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25364698/convert-utc-time-to-client-browsers-timezone-using-javascript-in-a-mvc-view)