# Android missing time zone?

Tags: android, xamarin, timezone

A client's Android app is reporting a `TimeZoneNotFoundException` for the following code/value (written in Xamarin):

```
TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("America/Los_Angeles");
```

How can this be? Are some Android devices missing some time zones? It works fine on our test devices and I have been unable to find anything on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

You must use Olson IDs.

http://www.mobtowers.com/xamarin-date-and-time-handling/
http://unicode.org/repos/cldr-tmp/trunk/diff/supplemental/zone_tzid.html

Or if you need to do it on the fly:

[.NET TimeZoneInfo from Olson time zone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5996320/net-timezoneinfo-from-olson-time-zone)

Comment: Sorry, I misread some of this info - it seems you are using an Olson ID. Is this with MonoTouch? I did find something about there being a bug with MonoTouch but that also said it was for iOS I believe.

Comment: `America/Los_Angeles` is definitely an Olson ID

Comment: Actually, I think the first link from @ThymeCypher may have the answer for your problem. It is located at the bottom of the article and it seems to be resolved by upgrading to Xamarin v4.8.2.